# problemas con el uso del json y ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

tengo el siguiente codigo ajax donde envio valores por medio de json a un php ya que estoy obteniendo valores desde un select, el problema es que creo que el php que debe recibir los datos no recibe ya que mando imprimir y me sale en la pantalla como valores null. la verdad soy muy nuevo en esto del json y ajax.

```
jQuery("#form_filtroscajas").submit(function( e ) {
var _servicio = $("#servicio").val();
var _producto = $("#producto").val();
var _estado = $("#estado").val();
var  datos = {servicio: _servicio, producto: _producto, estado: _estado}
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "ubicacion de mi php",
        data: datos, 
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){             
            if(data == "success"){
                 alert("correcto");
            }else{
                // alert(data);
                alert("error");
            }
            return false;
        },
        error: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            return;
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
        });
```

en donde yo debo recibir los datos los tengo asi

```
$servicio=$_POST['servicio'];
$producto=$_POST['producto'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$data = array('servicio' => $servicio,
              'producto' => $producto,
              'estado' => $estado );
//en el mismo php tengo este pedazo de codigo cosa que segun he leido debe de debolver los datos al ajax
// aqui es donde mando a imprimir igual el array que tengo para ver los valores pero este manda null
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: El html puede ayudar mucho en este caso, deberias ponerlo. por cierto porque haces una comprobacion de si `data === 'success'`, si se supone que lo que devuelve PHP es un string con la misma informacion que envias?

Comment: En principio veo dos problemas en tu código: 1. Si esperas un JSON, conviene indicarlo en la parte del Ajax, poniendo esto: `dataType: 'json'` 2. En la comprobación del `success` estás verificando esto: `if(data == "success"){`, lo cual, según la respuesta que estás enviando, nunca se cumplirá. Generalmente se pone una clave dentro de la respuesta para verificarla. O sea, para hacer ese estilo de verificación tendrías que poner en `$data` un par del tipo `'success'=>'Todo OK'` y comprobar así: `if(data.success){` Sea como sea, haz un `console.log(data);` siempre para depurar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio veo dos problemas en tu código:

1. Si esperas un JSON, conviene indicarlo en la parte del Ajax, poniendo esto: `dataType: 'json'`
2. En la comprobación del `success` estás verificando esto: `if(data == "success"){`, lo cual, según la respuesta que estás enviando, nunca se cumplirá. Generalmente se pone una clave dentro de la respuesta para verificarla. O sea, para hacer ese estilo de verificación tendrías que poner en `$data` un par del tipo `'success'=>'Todo OK'` (por ejemplo) y comprobar así: `if(data.success){`

Sea como sea, en fase de desarrollodo conviene siempre depurar la respuesta con un `console.log(data);` sin `if` ni nada.

También, es conveniente en PHP poner un `header` con el tipo de respuesta y la codificación. Eso ayuda, sobre todo cuando hay caracteres con acentos, que suelen dañar el JSON si no controlas la codificación.

Vamos a aplicar lo dicho en el código:

### JS

Muestro sólo la parte de Ajax a modificar

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "ubicacion de mi php",
        data: datos, 
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data); /*Usa esto siempre en fase de desarrollo*/             
            if(data.success){
                 alert("correcto");
            }else{
                // alert(data);
                alert("error");
            }
            return false;
        },
```

Todo lo demás igual ...

### PHP

```
/*
   Puedes usar un ternario para guardar los datos
   aquí se verifica con empty si los datos existen
   de ese modo evitas los undefined index y puedes usar luego
   las variables si hace falta verificar la existencia de datos requeridos
   sin los cuales el código no debe seguir adelante
*/
$servicio=!empty($_POST['servicio']) ? $_POST['servicio'] : NULL;
$producto=!empty($_POST['producto']) ? $_POST['producto'] : NULL;
$estado=  !empty($_POST['estado'])   ? $_POST['estado']   : NULL;
/* Nótese la creación de una clave success en el array */
$data = array(
                'success' =>'Todo Okey Manuel',
                'servicio' => $servicio,
                'producto' => $producto,
                'estado' => $estado 
              );

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias amigo realmente me funciono fue de muchisima ayuda todo eso ahora si me están retornando los valores a como deben de ser.